# How to rotate an actor in order to match a certain vector?

Tags: python, rotation, vtk, angle

I have a list of actors for arrowsources that I want to set their orientations pointing towards next actor location. But the orientations after running the code are not correct.

```
def CalculateOrientation(vec):
    #Here I use only one value of a particular vector before deviding it with its length because
 #I'm trying to find the angle between the given vector and the world's axes (X - 1, 0, 0; Y - 0, 1, 0; Z - 0, 0, 1;).
 #I know the formula is dot product divided by the multiplication of the lengths but since the values
 #are 1 or 0 for the world axes, I don't need to include them in the code.
    length = CalculateLength(vec)
    angleX = np.rad2deg(np.arccos(vec[0] / length))
    angleY = np.rad2deg(np.arccos(vec[1] / length))
    angleZ = np.rad2deg(np.arccos(vec[2] / length))

    return [angleX, angleY, angleZ]

def CalculateLength(vec):
    print np.sqrt(vec[0]**2 + vec[1]**2 + vec[2]**2)
    return np.sqrt(vec[0]**2 + vec[1]**2 + vec[2]**2)


def GetVectorBetweenPoints(a, b):
    vec = [b[0] - a[0], b[1] - a[1], b[2] - a[2]]
    return vec
for i in range(1338):  
    arrowsActors[i].SetOrientation(CalculateOrientation(GetVectorBetweenPoints(arrowsActors[i].GetPosition(), arrowsActors[i+1].GetPosition())))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could instead use SetUserMatrix(), and feed it a "look at" matrix, calculated the way [gluLookAt()](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/gluLookAt.xml) is calculated. You get to avoid using expensive trigonometry functions that way too.

I believe your math isn't working because rotation in one axis affects the lengths of the other two axes, look at the rotation matrix generated by [glRotatef()](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glRotate.xml) for an example.